# mostrar input ao selecionar um optin dentro do while do php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Bom dia!

pessoal é o seguinte, tenho um `combobox` que exibe todos os registro de uma tabela, até essa parte consegui desenrolar. No entanto, estou precisando mostrar um input quando um desses registros for selecionado e ocultar este mesmo input quando não tiver nada selecionado. A minha dificuldade ta na hora de pegar o valor option e fazer a comparação,segue o código da `combo`.

```
<label for="empresa">empresas *</label></a><br/>  
     <select name="empresa" id="empresa" 
      onchange="ExibirDiv(this.value)" class="form-control">
       <option value="">SELECIONE</option>
          <?php
             $parametro_empresa = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"parametro_empresa");
             $empresa = "SELECT * FROM tb_empresa WHERE 
             razaosocial_pessoafisica LIKE '%" . $parametro_empresa . "%'";                                          
             $recebe_empresas = mysqli_query($con, $empresa);
              while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($recebe_empresas)) {
               echo '<option value="' . $linha['codigo_empresa'] . '">' . 
               $linha['razaosocial_pessoafisica'] . '</option>';
             }
          ?>
     </select>
```

Comment: Explique-se melhor. Mostrar um input quando UM desses options for selecionado OU quando qualquer um desses options for selecionado?

Comment: opa, na verdade é quando qualquer um desses options for selecionado

Comment: Bem-vindo, se alguma resposta lhe serviu não deixe de marcá-la como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Comment: Leia esse post para que você entenda como funcionam as coisas por aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

**Verifique se há retorno do valor de algum `option` selecionado cujo `value` seja diferente de nulo.**

```js
function valida() {
var x = document.getElementById("empresa");
  if (x.options[x.selectedIndex].value != "" ){
      document.getElementById('idInput').style.display = "block";
  } else { 
      document.getElementById('idInput').style.display = "none";
  } 
}
```

```html
<label for="empresa">empresas *</label></a><br/>  
     <select name="empresa" id="empresa" 
      onchange="valida()" class="form-control">
       <option value="">SELECIONE</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
     </select>

  <input type="text" id="idInput"  style="display: none;">
```

Na verdade, em

```
 if (x.options[x.selectedIndex].value != "" ){
```

você pode colocar qualquer valor em `.value != ""` como por exemplo `.value != "qqvalor"`

Nesse caso o option cujo value é nulo

```
<option value="">SELECIONE</option>
```

deverá conter o value `qqvalor`, ou seja

```
<option value="qqvalor">SELECIONE</option>
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
function valida() {
var x = document.getElementById("empresa");
  if (x.options[x.selectedIndex].value != "qqvalor" ){
      document.getElementById('idInput').style.display = "block";
  } else { 
      document.getElementById('idInput').style.display = "none";
  } 
}
```

```html
<label for="empresa">empresas *</label></a><br/>  
     <select name="empresa" id="empresa" 
      onchange="valida()" class="form-control">
       <option value="qqvalor">SELECIONE</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
     </select>

  <input type="text" id="idInput"  style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá @user122281, vc pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
            $parametro_empresa = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"parametro_empresa");
             $empresa = "SELECT * FROM tb_empresa WHERE 
             razaosocial_pessoafisica LIKE '%" . $parametro_empresa . "%'";                                          

           $recebe_empresas = mysqli_query($con, $empresa);
              while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($recebe_empresas)) {

               $options [] = '<option value="' . $linha['codigo_empresa'] . '">' . 
               $linha['razaosocial_pessoafisica'] . '</option>';

               if($linha['codigo_empresa']==""){
                   $selected_option []="<option value=''>Selecione</option>"; 
               }else{
                   $selected_option []="<option value='$linha['codigo_empresa']'>$linha['razaosocial_pessoafisica']</option>"; 
               }
             }
          ?>

<label for="empresa">empresas *</label></a><br/>  
     <select name="empresa" id="empresa" 
      onchange="ExibirDiv(this.value)" class="form-control">
          <?php echo join($selected_option); ?>
          <?php echo join($options);  ?>
     </select>
```

- Para o $selected_option, coloque o where ID relacionado na sql para que filtre o valor especifico, ou crie uma sql direcionada a essa finalidade.